# Http Response with media HttpRequestHandler Android

Tags: java, android, apache

I am trying to create http server in android device by using apache http

**Here is my Thread**

```
public class RegisterThread extends Thread {


private boolean isRunning = false;

private BasicHttpProcessor httpproc = null;
private BasicHttpContext httpContext = null;
private HttpService httpService = null;
private HttpRequestHandlerRegistry registry = null;

public RegisterThread(Context context) {
    super(Constants.SERVER_NAME);

    httpproc = new BasicHttpProcessor();
    httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    httpproc.addInterceptor(new ResponseDate());
    httpproc.addInterceptor(new ResponseServer());
    httpproc.addInterceptor(new ResponseContent());
    httpproc.addInterceptor(new ResponseConnControl());
    httpService = new HttpService(httpproc,
            new DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy(),
            new DefaultHttpResponseFactory());
    registry = new HttpRequestHandlerRegistry();
    registry.register(Constants.ALL_PATTERN, new ResponseHandler(context));
    httpService.setHandlerResolver(registry);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    super.run();

    try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Constants.SERVER_PORT);

        serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);

        while (isRunning) {
            try {
                final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

                DefaultHttpServerConnection serverConnection = new DefaultHttpServerConnection();

                serverConnection.bind(socket, new BasicHttpParams());

                httpService.handleRequest(serverConnection, httpContext);

                serverConnection.shutdown();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (HttpException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   

        }

        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public synchronized void startThread() {
    isRunning = true;
    super.start();
}

public synchronized void stopThread() {
    isRunning = false;
}

}
```

**Here is Responsehandler**

```
public class ResponseHandler  implements HttpRequestHandler {
private Context context;
public ResponseHandler(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void handle(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response,
        HttpContext httpContext) throws HttpException, IOException {

    HttpEntity entity = new EntityTemplate(new ContentProducer() {
        public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream)
                throws IOException {
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outstream,
                    "UTF-8");
            String resp = Utility.openHTMLString(context, R.raw.home);
            writer.write(resp);
            writer.flush();
        }
    });
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    response.setEntity(entity);

}

}
```

This code can handle http response content type as html form as well and work for non media html content.

My question is how to handle media content here (eg. image).
My html page content some image tags. I'll already placed images inside (R.raw.mypic) but problem is this method can be used for single outputstream so I can only write one file at once.

Hope you understand my problem.I just need to load page which content image or similar media....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen each html elements (eg. image)

Here is sample

```
String uriString = request.getRequestLine().getUri();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
    if (uri != null) {
        if (uri.toString().contains("mypic.jpg")) {
            HttpEntity entity = new EntityTemplate(new ContentProducer() {
                public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream)
                        throws IOException {
                    InputStream is = context.getResources()
                            .openRawResource(R.raw.mypic);
                    copyStream(is, outstream);
                }
            });
            response.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpg");
            response.setEntity(entity);
        }
        else{
            HttpEntity entity = new EntityTemplate(new ContentProducer() {
                public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream)
                        throws IOException {
                    InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(
                            R.raw.home);
                    copyStream(is, outstream);
                }
            });
            response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
            response.setEntity(entity);
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help